# How can I use "read" to substitute user input inside a bash command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell

Was trying to do a quick-and-dirty curl call like so:

```
curl -u username:$(read -s -p "password: ") https://some.basic.auth.url.com
```

However, this fails every time.  What's more, I attempted to see what's happening with something like:

```
echo you entered: $(read -p "enter some text: ")
```

However, the output is simply:

```
you entered:
```

I'm clearly missing something essential about the use of this command (or Bash in general).  Can someone shed some light on:

1. Can this sort of thing even work?  why?
2. If so, how could I change this to make it work *without going to a script file*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "You entered: $(IFS= read -rp "Enter some text: "; printf '%s' "$REPLY")"
```

From `help read`:

> `read ... [name ...]`
>
> Reads a single line from the standard input ... The line is split into fields as with word
>   splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first `NAME`, the second
>   word to the second `NAME`, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>   the last `NAME`.  Only the characters found in `$IFS` are recognized as word
>   delimiters.
>
> If no `NAMEs` are supplied, the line read is stored in the `REPLY` variable.

- `IFS= ...`: Don't trim leading and trailing spaces
- `-r`: Don't mangle backslashes
- `echo "$REPLY"`: If you don't supply any `NAME`, the line read is stored in the `$REPLY` variable. However, `read` doesn't print it so the command substitution expands to nothing. Consequently, you have to print it explicitly with, for example, `printf`

Note that if you use `read` inside `$(...)`, the variable is lost as soon as you leave the substitution. Better approach:

```
IFS= read -rp "Enter some text: " var
echo "You entered: $var"
```

Comment: Yeah, but using a command subsititution is a really weird thing to do then. Just read a variable by normal reans first, then pass the variable to `curl`.

Comment: @tripleee haha :) I was just in the middle of writing that exact thing :)

Comment: Maybe also explain how `read` doesn't print the value as its output, which would make it near-imposible to use *outside* of a command substitution.

Comment: @tripleee feel free to edit the answer if I've left something out. Any input is appreciated :)

Comment: Ths gets my upvote already, though it doesn't really address the OP's (unfounded, and probably unwarranted) desire to do this "without a script" (which probably tries to mean "as a single command invocation").

Comment: @triplee - unfounded, yes.  But when I don't understand *why* something doesn't work, I want to.  Isn't that what S/O is about?  ;-)  I see where I was clearly failing to do this, but wanted to know more about why I was failing, what *would* workd, etc.  Thanks all for the good responses though, really helped me understand more about how this (hypothetically) can be used!

Comment: No objection to this particular question, but there *is* a very real and specific guidance to not ask just out of idle curiosity. If you have a requirement like "I cannot put this in a script" you will often need to explain why you have that requirement, because that sometimes brings in context and scope which helps guide the answers (perhaps you are using a build system which only allows you to put in a single command ... but then someone who knows that build system can tell you about another way to accomplish the same thing more easily with that build system, for example).

Comment: I see.  That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The `read` part can be put in a `bash` function, with a *local variable*, which would make the code cleaner:

```
password(){ local password; read -s -p "password: " password; echo "${password}"; }
```

Usage:

```
curl -u username:"$(password)" https://some.basic.auth.url.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what would be wrong with simply doing a read && echo combo? I was looking to use read command output as a substitution and thus a search lead me here.  I quickly figured out something that works for me and I see no reason why it would not work for op. I needed to get a quick output of a bmc sensor using ipmitool reading the sensor indicated by user input. I knew I could not just use read as is but was not sure then realized I could do this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# printf "%d\n" "0x$(ipmitool raw 0x4 0x2d 0x$(read -p 'id: ' r && echo ${r:-00})|awk '{print $1}')"
id: 
0
[root@localhost ~]# printf "%d\n" "0x$(ipmitool raw 0x4 0x2d 0x$(read -p 'id: ' r && echo ${r:-00})|awk '{print $1}')"
id: 0f
73
```

*note use of ${var:-*default*} so that no input defaults 00. output of command we are interested in is the second field which is in hex and needs to be converted.. well I mean it doesn't actually *need* to be, but to each their own lol. I am no expert in anything but I don't see this breaking anywhere except pure posix maybe.

**raw code for ipmitool are not specific to any platform that I know of. I actually learned them here https://github.com/erik-smit/oohhh-what-does-this-ipmi-doooo-no-deedee-nooooo/blob/master/1-discovering/snippets/Computercheese/IPMI-Sensor%20Device%20Commands.txt and there are many other very useful ones documented not just for ipmitool but various other ipmi interfaces.